# Switch to mobile site on standard browser

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-web

At the moment I am using damn slow dialup internet and desperately need a link to switch to mobile site for faster browsing.

There should be a link to switch to mobile site also in desktop web browser.

Comment: While the link works, each site automatically switches back to desktop view after some time (haven't exactly measured but I think it's after about 2 weeks of non-visiting the site). Any way to permanently force mobile view (preferably across all SE sites)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a link to switch from desktop to mobile view in the footer of any page on Stack Exchange:

> [image: mobile link]

Comment: Oops, I missed that :)

Comment: Tiny link on a tiny page on my phone...so, so sad.

Comment: @Kit many sites don't have such option at all.

Comment: While the link works, each site automatically switches back to desktop view after some time (haven't exactly measured but I think it's after about 2 weeks of non-visiting the site). Any way to permanently force mobile view (preferably across all SE sites)?