# Mobile version on P.SE - How to get back to it?

Tags: support, mobile-web, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch to mobile site on standard browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104458/switch-to-mobile-site-on-standard-browser)

A few days ago, I was navigating through programmers.se, wandering around.

Suddenly, while the bus was making me do some weird touching on the screen, I turned to the desktop version of the website.

I have not found a single way to turn back to the mobile version. Appending `?mobile=true` to the URL didn't do anything.

I do not want to clear the cookies, I'm using them on other websites and it's a pain to write on the phone. Also, there is no way to delete cookies for a single site on my Android.

So, is there any clean way to go back to the mobile version?

Comment: I think we need a new tag or flag or something: "Answerable with freehand circles".

Comment: @UristMcBobby Damn, I feel stupid for not seeing it. I did watch the footer's links, I guess my eyes were tired.

Comment: For my defense, the people in the javascript SO chat couldn't answer me either yesterday.

Comment: in our defence, both users who answered where directed here from the JS room. :P

Comment: Yeah, obviously, it was the JavaScript and not the Meta chat. ;P

Comment: `while the bus was making me do some weird touching` Out of context, that's amazingly creepy ;)

Comment: In context, knowing Florian... this should still be viewed as creepy.

Comment: As for `?mobile=true` not working, that [has its reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98925/serious-xsrf-bug-in-the-new-mobile-theme).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a link in the footer.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Click me!]