# Printing an SE page in Firefox shows only the first page

Tags: bug, design, firefox, printing

I used to print Q&A pages to keep a base of PDFs. I used either the 'print edit' addon or simply the print function of Firefox, which both allow to print a webpage in a file.

Usually the printed file for a webpage extends on 2 or 3 pages.
But I'm not able to print more than one page on this site expressly anymore. No matter the method. I just get the top of each discussion.

Comment: Reproduced. Not sure what's causing it, though; I suspect something funny in the CSS. As a work-around, printing from the [mobile view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104458/switch-to-mobile-site-on-standard-browser) seems to work fine.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the use of flex layout on the `<body>` element. Injecting `body { display: block !important }` as a user style seems to fix it with no (immediately obvious) harmful side effects.

Comment: Firefox itself has some printing issues (not just with SE sites). They are intermittent, but FF has occasionally only printed the first page of other non-SE sites for me.

Comment: Fixed: [This comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317013/css-bug-with-printing-site-pages-now-with-100-more-suggested-fix-included#comment1038860_317013), or the accepted answer.