# CSS bug with printing site pages (now with 100% more suggested fix included!)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, printing

So I have to print some Stack Overflow pages and bring them around. Just accept it.

Problem: while pages may look perfectly normal on the web, something recently broke the print layout... a huge whitespace block showed up on the right ([normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb9gH.png), [print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrBV1.png)). Tons of whitespace. This is on every site on the network ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuc6r.png)) on a bunch of different screens ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cycIf.png)).

Futzing with DevTools, the problem seems to be [the following piece of css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VChWN.png):

```
#mainbar, .mainbar {
    width: calc(100% - 300px - 24px);
}
```

Can someone check if this is the only issue and possibly fix this?

Comment: Print probably should not show the navigation sidebar, either, but that change looks like it would be a nice-to-have compared to at minimum getting rid of that huge space on the right.

Comment: @Sonic - see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cycIf.png), not just a problem for printing questions... it's on a bunch of other pages as well.

Comment: Just wanted to make it clear the question was on-topic, as we do get a lot of off-topic questions which others vote to close quickly without much thought.

Comment: Always recommended: [Stack Printer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62937/241919)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fixed.

[image: Screenshot of print dialog.]

Our previous style rules were more or less, "If we're printing, hide this list of elements."

Now, it's a lot smarter, thanks to responsive design.  We have a few methods for handling responsive breakpoints:

```
.if-responsive-and-below-breakpoint(@breakpoint, @rules)
.if-responsive-and-above-breakpoint(@breakpoint, @rules)
.if-responsive-and-between-breakpoints(@smaller-breakpoint, @larger-breakpoint, @rules)
```

These methods let you turn on extra styles if you're on a narrow screen.  For example, the following code constrains page content to accommodate a sidebar.  When the page gets narrow, the width expands and the sidebar moves below the main content.

```
#mainbar,
.mainbar {
    width: ~'calc(100% - @{sidebar-width} - @{su-24})'; // 100% - width sidebar - spacing between sidebar and content

    .if-responsive-and-below-breakpoint(@breakpoint-l, {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    });
}
```

I simply amended `if-responsive-and-below-breakpoint` to treat printed pages as the narrower than any breakpoint, so it would render in the same way as a mobile view:

```
.if-responsive-and-below-breakpoint(@breakpoint, @rules) {
    // ...

    // Print is the smallest viewport, below medium and large
    @media print {
        @rules();
    }
}
```

I also added some small refinements, hiding a few elements like "Ask Question" as well as removing some vertical padding from the hidden topbar.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a fix for the main site but using the mobile site to print pages works fine  [image]

Here is a preview of the printout.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The suggested fix is correct. It seems that the CSS in question (`width: calc(100% - 300px - 24px);`) is used to reduce the width to make space for the sidebar, which is 300 pixels wide with a 24 pixels left margin. However, the sidebar is hidden (with `display:none`) in print view, but the width of the content section is not allowed to fill the remaining space.

I wrote some JavaScript code which appends a style block with the appropriate CSS ruleset so that the width is set to 100%, but only in print view. It also executes the `window.print()` function. The code can be used as a bookmarklet (by copying the code to your bookmark toolbar).

Here is the code:

```
(function() {
    var css = '@media print {#mainbar, .mainbar {width: 100%;}}';
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

    document.head.appendChild(style);
    window.print();
})();
```

To use it, just run the following snippet and then drag the link into your bookmark toolbar. The code is in the link, but minified.

```html
<a href="javascript:(function(){var css='@media print {#mainbar, .mainbar {width: 100%;}}';var style=document.createElement('style');style.type='text/css';style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));document.head.appendChild(style);window.print()})();">Print with Fix</a>
```

This of course is just a workaround while we wait for the real fix.

By the way, the real fix would simply look like this:

```
@media print {
    #mainbar, .mainbar {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```